# How to copy only numbers from one array to another

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I haven't written anything in VB in several years. I am taking a intermediate class and am running into an issue. I am working on an invoice program that is suppose to take the user entered data from a textbox( city state and zip) and use only the zip as the invoice number. I have made an array that stores the user data but I can't figure out how to iterate through it and only write the numeric values to another array. Once that is done I will need to iterate through the second array and write the array contents to a string so it can be displayed as the invoice number. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
'the array that holds the user city state and zip

Dim UserZip As String = txtCItyStateZip.Text
Dim UserArray() As Char = UserZip.ToCharArray
Dim ZipArray(4) As Integer

For num As Integer = 0 To UserArray.Length - 1
    If IsNumeric(num) Then
        ZipArray(num)
        num += 1
    End If
Next`
```

Comment: remove `n += 1` line. `For loop` will increase value automatically

Comment: If you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) it may point out some problems with your code and even suggest fixes. For example, the line `ZipArray(num)` does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save zip numbers as array of `char` and use constructor of type `string` which takes `char` array as parameter .

```
Dim UserZip As String = txtCItyStateZip.Text
Dim UserArray() As Char = UserZip.ToCharArray
Dim ZipChars As New List(Of Char)()

For num As Integer = 0 To UserArray.Length - 1
    Dim character As Char = UserArray(num)
    If IsNumeric(character) Then
        ZipArray.Add(character)
    End If
Next

Dim ZipCode As String = New String(ZipChars.ToArray())
```

Use `List(Of Char)` for saving zip's characters, because in cases when zip will contain more then 4 numbers you code will throw exception.

Comment: Downvoter - please explain, so I can to fix/improve an answer

Comment: Thanks for all the help and fast response. This worked fantastically.

Answer (score -1):

IsNumeric(num) will always return True. It should be

```
For num As Integer = 0 To UserArray.Length - 1
   If IsNumeric(UserArray(num)) Then
      ZipArray.Add(UserArray(num))
   End If
Next
```

Comment: `ZipArray` is array type, which haven't `Add` method